# Sequential execution of Ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The script should take the user's session via ajax and transfer it to other ajax requests that take the data for the charts. The first request succeeds, but others have not, becouse sessionId for them is undefined. Tried to wrap them in a function, but unfortunately nothing happened. What can be done?

```
var sessionId,
    requestInWorkCount,
    requestInWorkPower;

function getSession(){
  $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.142/DashboardService.svc/web/jsonLoginUser?UserID=User1&UserPassword=123", {},
                    function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                      sessionId = val.toString();
                      return sessionId;
                    })
                });
};

function getData(session){
      $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.142/DashboardService.svc/web/jsonGetIndicator?SessionID="+session+"&IndNum=1", {},
                function(data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                  requestInWorkCount = val;
                  return requestInWorkCount;
                })
            });
      $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.142/DashboardService.svc/web/jsonGetIndicator?SessionID="+session+"&IndNum=2", {},
                function(data) {
                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                  requestInWorkCount = val;
                  return requestInWorkPower;
                })
              });
    };
$(document).ready(function(){
  getSession();
  getData(sessionId);
  setInterval('show()',1000); 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ajax call is **async** so your second ajax call is executed before the first completes thats the reason `sessionId` is undefined.

Use the success function of first ajax call and call `GetData()` in it.

Also you don't need to return `sessionId`

```
function getSession(){
  $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.142/DashboardService.svc/web/jsonLoginUser?UserID=User1&UserPassword=123", {},
                    function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                      sessionId = val.toString();
                      getData(sessionId);

                    })
                });
};
```

you call like this now:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      getSession();


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The AJAX request are asynchronous and you cannot execute them sequentially.

An easy solution here would be to call `getData()` inside AJAX success block:

```
function getSession() {
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.142/DashboardService.svc/web/jsonLoginUser?UserID=User1&UserPassword=123", {}, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            sessionId = val.toString();
            getData(sessionId);
            return sessionId;
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to take the RESPONSE of the ajax request. You do not return it, I believe. But in your code you should perhaps do

```
sessionId = getSession();
getData(sessionId);
```

You forgot to dereference what it returned.

Comment: $.getJSON returns an jqXHR object, not the response of the call.